# CakePHP: $this->Model->contain(...) changes search results for DIFFERENT model

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

We noticed that when we use `find()` after a `contain()` method from a *different* controller, it alters the results...

Inside ModelAController...

public function index() {

```
$this->ModelA->contain(...); //this affects the next find()

$this->loadModel('ModelB');
$var = $this->ModelB->find('all');
```

}

When the `contain()` method above is removed the find() works normally. Why?

Comment: Are there any associations between `ModelA` and `ModelB`? By calling the `contain` method, you will alter `ModelA`'s state but how that is interrelated with `ModelB` is less clear. I strongly suggest you post the contents of `$this->element('sql_dump')` to help others here identify what's really going on.

Answer (score 1):

As written in the CakePHP Documentation:

> Containable allows you to streamline and simplify operations on your model bindings. **It
>   works by temporarily or permanently altering the associations of your models.** It does this
>   by using supplied the containments to generate a series of bindModel and unbindModel calls.

The unbind / bind Model functions work (if not specified with the right parameter) only for the first "find" call. Maybe the "contain" call doesnt release at all the effect of the internal unbind / bind calls performed.

What would I do in your case? Try performing your find using something like this:

```
$this->Model->find('all', array('contain' => array(/* YOUR DIRECTIVES */), 'conditions' => array('/* YOUR CONDITIONS */));
```

Maybe this will release the effect of the unbind / bind calls. Give it a try!

Obviously, remember to attach the "Containable" Behaviour to your model ;)